# Ubuntu App Development Cookbook

Tags: application-development

Is there any book available for studying Ubuntu SDK. The documentation may be enough, but it lacks a real flow. After the introduction chapters it becomes a bit confusing. I really want to do application development on Ubuntu and I am not getting from where to study about QML and the Ubuntu SDK. Is there any PDF version of the cookbook available at [here](http://developer.ubuntu.com/resources/cookbook/)?

Comment: Why do you want a pdf version of Cookbook? The website should be sufficient, and the website is going to up-to-date where as the PDF will be out of date as soon as you download it.

Answer (score 1):

> The App Developer Cookbook is a collection of short examples, how to’s
>   and answered questions from our developer community. In the sections
>   below you will find information about how to perform common tasks,
>   answers to frequently asked questions, and code snippets from real
>   world examples.

For more info, check out [Ubuntu App Developer Resources Cookbook](http://developer.ubuntu.com/resources/cookbook/)

You may also look at [Introduction to Web Applications Development Guide](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/download-introduction-to-web-applications-development-guide-pdf.html)

The [Mono Project](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page)

The [Ubuntu App Developers](https://www.facebook.com/ubuntuappdev?directed_target_id=0)

Also check out [The Ubuntu App Developer Cookbook Announced](http://www.jonobacon.org/2013/06/14/the-ubuntu-app-developer-cookbook-announced/)

As far as a PDF, I can't find any at this time.  That doesn't mean that it might not be available later.

<sup>Source:[Ubuntu App Developer](http://developer.ubuntu.com/resources/cookbook/)</sup>

Comment: So first,I start studying  QML and JAVA Script and make command over them and then I should enter into App Development.

Answer (score 0):

(I know this doesn't directly answer your question about a PDF version of the Ubuntu App Development Cookbook, but hopefully it will help you get started developing for Ubuntu Touch)

To study QML, I'd suggest taking a look at [the Qt Project website](http://qt-project.org/), and also [the Qt Quick getting started guide](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtdoc/gettingstartedqml.html).

For learning the Ubuntu Touch SDK, I'd study [the Ubuntu SDK documentation](http://developer.ubuntu.com/api/ubuntu-12.10/qml/mobile/overview-ubuntu-sdk.html).

You could also look at the [Ubuntu Development Getting Started page](http://developer.ubuntu.com/get-started/) and [the example app tutorial](http://developer.ubuntu.com/resources/tutorials/getting-started/currency-converter-phone-app/).